# Inky pHAT compatibility issues with Raspberry Pi 4B

Tags: gpio, pi-4, hat, eink

I've bought a Raspberry Pi Model 4B for a few different projects, one of which is to use an Inky pHAT display (as seen on [The Pi Hut](https://thepihut.com/products/inky-phat?variant=12272180330558)) on it.

When the display arrived, I attached it to the Pi's GPIO pins (yes, the right way around) and followed the developers' tutorials on [GitHub](https://github.com/pimoroni/inky) and [their blog](https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/sandyj/getting-started-with-inky-phat). All the installation steps were successful.

But when running the example scripts, they would always get stuck on the Inky's `show()` function, even though I did wait longer than a refresh would take. At first I thought the display or its board were broken but after trying it on an old Raspberry Pi 1 B+ **and** a Pi 3B (see image) it worked fine out-of-the-box while also using the exact same Raspbian installation (simply switching the SD card). I also went through all the configuration steps again on all devices.

[image: Working Inky pHAT on Raspberry Pi 3B]

Does anyone here know about any problems with the Inky pHAT or similar (p)HAT devices due to changes in the hardware from the Raspberry Pi 3 to 4 which could be causing my problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered asking Pimoroni directly? https://forums.pimoroni.com/

Comment: @Dirk Thanks for the suggestion. I've just asked the question there as well: [Link](https://forums.pimoroni.com/t/inky-phat-compatibility-issues-with-raspberry-pi-4b/13794)